# Part (b) of Exercise 13 of first chapter of Rudin's book "Functional Analysis"

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I would really appreciate it if you could give me some advice on the part (b) of Exercise 13 of first chapter of Walter Rudin's book "Functional Analysis":

> Let $C$ be the vector space of all complex continuous functions on $[0, 1]$. Define
>   \begin{equation}
> d(f,g) = \int_0^1 \frac{\lvert f(x) - g(x) \rvert}{1 + \lvert f(x) - g(x) \rvert} \ dx \ .
> \end{equation}
>   Let $(C, \sigma)$ be $C$ with the topology induced by this metric. Let $(C, \tau)$ be the topological vector space defined by the semi-norms
>   \begin{equation}
> P_x(f) = \lvert f(x) \rvert, \qquad (0 \leq x \leq 1),
> \end{equation}
>
> (a) Prove that every $\tau$-bounded set in $C$ is also $\sigma$-bounded and that the identity map $id: (C, \tau) \rightarrow (C, \sigma)$ therefore carries bounded sets into bounded sets.
>
> (b) Prove that $id: (C, \tau) \rightarrow (C, \sigma)$ is nevertheless not continuous, although it is sequentially continuous (by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem). Hence $(C, \tau)$ is not metrizable. Show
>   also directly that $(C, \tau)$ has no countable local base.

First part of this question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330795/tau-bounded-sets-is-also-sigma-bounded), but I have no idea solving the second part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ask one question per question, and help us to understand what is causing you a problem by explaining what you have tried to do.

Comment: @MarkBennet OK, thanks. I will correct it soon.

Comment: [Look here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874783/semi-norms-in-functional-analysis?rq=1)