# Part (c) of Exercise 13 of first chapter of Rudin's book "Functional Analysis"

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I would really appreciate it if you could give me some advice on the part (c) of Exercise 13 of first chapter of Walter Rudin's book "Functional Analysis":

> Let $C$ be the vector space of all complex continuous functions on $[0, 1]$. Define
>   \begin{equation}
> d(f,g) = \int_0^1 \frac{\lvert f(x) - g(x) \rvert}{1 + \lvert f(x) - g(x) \rvert} \ dx \ .
> \end{equation}
>   Let $(C, \sigma)$ be $C$ with the topology induced by this metric. Let $(C, \tau)$ be the topological vector space defined by the semi-norms
>   \begin{equation}
> P_x(f) = \lvert f(x) \rvert, \qquad (0 \leq x \leq 1),
> \end{equation}
>
> (a) Prove that every $\tau$-bounded set in $C$ is also $\sigma$-bounded and that the identity map $id: (C, \tau) \rightarrow (C, \sigma)$ therefore carries bounded sets into bounded sets.
>
> (b) Prove that $id: (C, \tau) \rightarrow (C, \sigma)$ is nevertheless not continuous, although it is sequentially continuous (by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem). Hence $(C, \tau)$ is not metrizable. Show
>   also directly that $(C, \tau)$ has no countable local base.
>
> (c) Prove that every continuous linear functional on $(C, \tau)$ is of the form
>   \begin{equation}
> f \rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n c_i f(x_i)
> \end{equation}
>   for some choice of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ in $[0, 1]$ and some $c_i \in \mathbb{C}$.

First part of this question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330795/tau-bounded-sets-is-also-sigma-bounded) and the second part is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330710/part-b-of-exercise-13-of-first-chapter-of-rudins-book-functional-analysis). I have no idea solving the third part too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general fact about a TVS $X$ defined by a family of seminorms $\{\rho_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in J}$ (which is perhaps proved in the textbook before this):

> Theorem: If $\varphi : X\to \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous linear functional, then $\exists C>0$ and $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\ldots, \alpha_n \in J$ such that
>   $$
> |\varphi(x)| \leq C \sum_{j=1}^n \rho_{\alpha_j}(x)
> $$

Applying this to your present situation tells you that if $\varphi : C \to \mathbb{C}$ is a $\tau$-continuous linear functional, then $\exists C > 0$ and $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n \in [0,1]$ such that
$$
|\varphi(f)| \leq C \sum_{j=1}^n |f(x_i)|
$$
Now consider the linear functionals $\varphi_x : f \mapsto f(x)$ and note that 
$$
\cap_{j=1}^n \ker(\varphi_{x_i}) \subset \ker(\varphi)
$$
and so you get your result.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Can you explain a bit more on how can I get the result please?

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709781/intersection-of-kernels-implies-linear-dependence-of-functionals

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, you are the best ;)

Comment: @Hossein Moradi Davijani Hi, can you point out a reference for the inequality in your answer? Rudin doesn't seem to have one and I can't derive it myself.

Comment: @user8469759 It's from 5 years ago. I don't have any idea what's this question about :)) BTW, the answer is from Prahlad Vaidyanathan.

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan could you please give a reference for the inequality?