# Part (e) of Exercise 13 of first chapter of Rudin's book "Functional Analysis"

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I would really appreciate it if you could give me some advice on the part (e) of Exercise 13 of first chapter of Walter Rudin's book "Functional Analysis":

> Let $C$ be the vector space of all complex continuous functions on $[0, 1]$. Define
>   \begin{equation}
> d(f,g) = \int_0^1 \frac{\lvert f(x) - g(x) \rvert}{1 + \lvert f(x) - g(x) \rvert} \ dx \ .
> \end{equation}
>   Let $(C, \sigma)$ be $C$ with the topology induced by this metric. Let $(C, \tau)$ be the topological vector space defined by the semi-norms
>   \begin{equation}
> P_x(f) = \lvert f(x) \rvert, \qquad (0 \leq x \leq 1),
> \end{equation}
>
> (a) Prove that every $\tau$-bounded set in $C$ is also $\sigma$-bounded and that the identity map $id: (C, \tau) \rightarrow (C, \sigma)$ therefore carries bounded sets into bounded sets.
>
> (b) Prove that $id: (C, \tau) \rightarrow (C, \sigma)$ is nevertheless not continuous, although it is sequentially continuous (by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem). Hence $(C, \tau)$ is not metrizable. Show
>   also directly that $(C, \tau)$ has no countable local base.
>
> (c) Prove that every continuous linear functional on $(C, \tau)$ is of the form
>   \begin{equation}
> f \rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n c_i f(x_i)
> \end{equation}
>   for some choice of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ in $[0, 1]$ and some $c_i \in \mathbb{C}$.
>
> (d) Prove that $(C, \sigma)$ contains no convex open sets other than $\varnothing$ and $C$.
>
> (e) Prove that $id: (C, \sigma) \rightarrow (C, \tau)$ is not continuous.

First part of this question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330795/tau-bounded-sets-is-also-sigma-bounded), the second part is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330710/part-b-of-exercise-13-of-first-chapter-of-rudins-book-functional-analysis), the third part is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330822/part-c-of-exercise-13-of-first-chapter-of-rudins-book-functional-analysis) and the fourth part is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330972/part-d-of-exercise-13-of-first-chapter-of-rudins-book-functional-analysis). I have no idea solving this part too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you can find a non-trivial convex open set in $\tau$? (Hint: Look for a subbasic open set)

Comment: Could you explain it a bit more please?

Comment: If $\tau$ contains a non-trivial convex open set, then its inverse image under the identity map (namely itself) cannot be in $\sigma$ by part (d).

Comment: Thanks, this sounds a good idea. Do you have any idea to find such a set?